# Extract specific table data using Jsoup

Tags: android, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm trying to extract the football fixtures from this [Webpage.](http://www.bbc.com/sport/football/spanish-la-liga/fixtures) Right now I've this code for extracting the fixtures from the table of that webpage.

```
private class LoadFixtures extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    String stringDT="",stringHome="",stringAway="";
    String url = "http://www.bbc.com/sport/football/spanish-la-liga/fixtures";
    String stringTime="";
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(0).get();

            Elements matchDetails = doc.select("td.match-details");
            Elements ele_hTeam = matchDetails.select("span.team-home.teams");
            Elements ele_aTeam = doc.select("span.team-away.teams");
            Elements ele_time = doc.select("td.kickoff");

            int tsize = ele_hTeam.size();
            for(int i=0;i<tsize;i++) {
                stringTime+="\n\n"+ele_time.get(i).text();
                stringHome+="\n\n"+ele_hTeam.get(i).text();
                stringAway+="\n\n"+ele_aTeam.get(i).text();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
      homeTeam.setText(stringHome);
       awayTeam.setText(stringAway);
        timeView.setText(stringTime);

        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

    }
}
```

This code gives me the whole list of fixtures, but what i want to do is just extract the fixtures of specific date. For example, lets say i want to extract the fixtures only from **Saturday 16th January 2016**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will do as you ask. I have simply supplied a String variable with the date you are looking up. The code below loops on each table on the page. Each table will contain x number of fixtures. If the tables caption contains the date you have provided it will enter this table and allow you to select the home team and the away team. Hope this helps!

```
String dateLookup= "16th January 2016";
String url = "http://www.bbc.com/sport/football/spanish-la-liga/fixtures";

try {
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(0).get();
    Elements tableElements = document.select("table.table-stats");
    for (Element e : tableElements) {
        if (e.select("caption").text().contains(dateLookup)) {
            Elements matchElements = e.select("tr.preview");
            for (Element match : matchElements) {
                System.out.println("Home Team: " + match.select("span.team-home").text());
                System.out.println("Away Team: " + match.select("span.team-away").text() + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```